# How do I include Home custom page layout in package.xml?

Tags: force.com-ide, package.xml

I have created new Page layout for Home page for specific profile. I am having trouble deploying that from One environment to another. Here is my pakcge.xml looks like to retrieve that layout. But this does not retrieve this home layout to my Project Directory in eclipse.

```
 <types>
                <members>Home-Service Layout</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
     </types>
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [HomePageLayout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_homepagelayouts.htm) to customize the Home tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `.homePageLayout` files extracted into a `homePageLayout` folder if you want to retrieve a specific layout:

```
<types>
    <members>Service Home</members>
    <name>HomePageLayout</name>
</types>
```

If you want to retrieve all layouts:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>HomePageLayout</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Keith. If I want to just retrieve one layout can I do 

<members>Layout Name</members> or <members>Home-layout name</members>

Comment: Tried that with layout name direct without Home. And could retrieve. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @Ricky Sure just make sure the names exactly match what you have used in the "Home Page Layouts" section of setup.